# HTML attribute encoding the value attribute of an INPUT tag in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, html-encode

My problem is to do with attribute encoding data from the database into the value attribute of an INPUT tag.  I need to know what the best practice in this situation is. I want to safely render this into the value tag of an INPUT tag.

My data in the DB (note the ampersand): **Me & You**

I'm using a class to attribute encode value as follows (this is a derivation of the OWASP XSS prevention class):

```
<INPUT ID="test" VALUE="<% =Encode.HtmlAttribute(theDBValue) %>" />
```

This appears as ...

```
Me &amp; You
```

...in the textbox when viewed on screen, which is not what the customer will want to see. They'll want to see "Me & You".

How can I safely output the data?

Comment: I don't think you should encode value of the input - what happens if you simple display the value? And why do u use encoding here anyway?

Comment: What is the rendered HTML that gets sent to the client? Is it `VALUE="Me &amp; You"` or `VALUE="Me &amp;amp; You"`? Have you verified the `Encode` class is working correctly?

Comment: Yuriy, It needs to be encoded to prevent malicious code (from the database) rendering on the page. It could for instance include text to close the value attribute, close the input tag and then start some javascript.

Comment: Cheran, you hit the nail on the head!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that there was function further up the page that was partially applying some encoding, specifically the ampersand was being encoded. Thus my function as shown above, was double-encoding the value.